# Angular creating a reactive form component twice, displaying one and applying the directives to the other

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-reactive-forms

So I have got an angular 2 , specifically 6 reactive form component,
this component is embedded inside another container component , that is displayed using the angular cdk overlay.

- the overlay is the cdk overlay service, nothing weird there.
- the container component has the reactive form

Container component

```
<form [FormGroup]="form">
<div  class="column col-5 col-mx-auto">
<reactive-form-component formControlName="dateField"></reactive-form-component>
</form>
```

Reactive component bellow

```
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

import {
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  ControlValueAccessor,
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl
} from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'er-alt-reactive-form-component',
  templateUrl: './alt-reactive-form-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./er-alt-reactive-form-component.css'],
  providers: [
{
     provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useClass: forwardRef(() => AltReactiveFormComponentComponent)
    }
  ]
})
export class AltReactiveFormComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, 
OnDestroy {

 constructor( private _fb:FormBuilder) {
 console.log('cons')
}

   registerOnChange(onChange: any): void {
     console.log('c', onChange);
     console.log(this);
     // this._onChange = (x) => console
     this._onChange = onChange;
     console.log(this._onChange === onChange);
   }

   registerOnTouched(onTouch: any): void {
     console.log(this);
     console.log('t', onTouch);
     this._onTouch = onTouch;
     console.log(this._onTouch === onTouch);
   }

   }
```

on touched and on change are private 
very stripped down version, same error displayed though
https://angular-1tzuhj.stackblitz.io --- stackblitz preview
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1tzuhj 
any ideas on what the heck is happening ?

Comment: So , for the sake of posterity i leave this here, i found the issue . I used useClass instead of useExisting

Answer (score 0):

So , for the sake of posterity i leave this here, i found the issue . I used useClass instead of useExisting. which caused the issue